# Integrated Onlyoffice Documentserver in Owncloud Documents are not syncable anylonger

Tags: file, synchronization, owncloud, onlyoffice

I integrated Onlyoffice Documentserver into my Owncloud Instance.
Now I cannot sync my files from Owncloud, because they are hidden and renamed for onlyoffice usage. Now I see files named .Table.xlsx~34324fs
something like that.

Also the directory structure is not mirrored to the webspace directory as usual....

Is Documentserver storing all the files and directory now?

Is there a opportunity to sync the files from owncloud as usual?

Answer (score 0):

> because they are hidden and renamed for onlyoffice usage

I can assure you that ONLYOFFICE doesn't rename/change the files, it works with your existing files. The files are saved with the same names after the editing process is completed.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution simply sync over davs protocol working like a charme...